# DateTime Format get only the hours

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get the Time only in the DateTime?

Example

01/27/12 04:00PM

i want only to display 04:00PM is there a way to get that? :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - just specify a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) which only includes the information you want. For example, "hh:mmtt" would do what you want here, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use ToString method with options:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mmtt")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(01/27/12 04:00PM);
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:H:mm:ss zzz}", 
                   thisDate1);
```

For more help please visit this link [Custom date formate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)